# Laravel password reset implementation

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I'm really new to Laravel. I tried to implement the default auth, all so far went good until I hit the Reset password flow, I got the url with the token but every time I enter the token it says "Token Invalid", I traced the flow in the vendor folder to the hasher check function and then I noticy that is trying to use the password_verify function but both values that are reaching there are hashes, it looks like it's trying to verify if the token received in the url is the same that is stored in the DB, so why use the password_verify function....

The flow I followed is like this

```
File                                   Function       Obs
Auth/ResetsPassword                    reset          Line 43 makes next call
Auth/Passwords/PasswordBrocker         reset          Line 88
Auth/Passwords/PasswordBrocker         validateReset  Line 122
Auth/Passwords/DatabaseTokenRepository exists         Line 128
Hasshing/BcryptHasher                  check          Line53
```

verify_password expect first parameter to be a plain string and the second one to be a hash, but if the token is being passed as both parameters then it always fails.

Not sure if I have something wrong, or this is an issue that is already fixed. Currently running Laravel 5.4.7. If any other info is needed let me know to post it.

Comment: Just a hint, but whenever I've received the `Token Invalid` error, it's usually because my Session storage hasn't been setup correctly. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#configuration It might help, but it might not, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks Phil, already checked all fine, but still got the issue. Basically I feel that part of the implementation is somehow not right, but I don't have enought laravel background yet, but I'll keep digging :)

Comment: did you do `php artisan make:auth`? or trying to implement yourself

Comment: any update on this? I have been fighting this exact same thing for a day now.

Comment: @Jorge Escribens  I have same problem, if you have solution for same, please let me know